# HTML Form submit not working as expected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am trying to do a simple form submit, which will take my application to another url in another domain. I have seen it working on my SYS environment but when I am doing that on Prod, it does not work.

For ex, my website is something like this https://dosomething.com/Index

The value from document.getElementById("hidUrl").value is like https://anotherdomain.com/id=1

Ideally when the form submits, I should be redirected to the page https://www.anotherdomain.com/id=1 (which is what I have seen on my test server) but on production, it is taking me to https://dosomething.com/Index/www.anotherdomain.com/id=1 and I am getting 404 error

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I am not sure why is this happening. Has anyone have got any idea?

Much appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitAuthenticationForm() {
            document.getElementById("userName").value = document.getElementById("hidUserName").value;
            document.getElementById("token").value = document.getElementById("hidToken").value;
            document.getElementById("hiddenForm").action = document.getElementById("hidUrl").value; 
            document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:submitAuthenticationForm();">
    <form method="post" id="hiddenForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUserName" runat="server"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidToken" runat="server"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUrl" runat="server"/>   
        </div>  
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the code behind cs file doing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        hidUserName.Value = Session["authUserName"].ToString();
        hidToken.Value = Session["authToken"].ToString(); 
        hidUrl.Value = Session["authUrl"].ToString();

        Session["authUserName"] = null;
        Session["authToken"] = null;
        Session["authUrl"] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your controller/code behind code? That's probably where the redirect is happening.

Comment: It seems very likely that the bug is not in the ASP markup, but rather in the code-behind CS file, where you set the value of hidUrl. If you cannot see the bug, please post the contents of the CS file.

Comment: There is nothing happening in the code behind file. All it is doing is setting up the values of hidden fields through session. Edited the question to provide details of the code behind file.

Comment: Have you verified the value in the hidden field on your production server prior to doing the submission?  The behavior you describe would occur if hidUrl was missing the https:// prefix, and thus would get treated as a relative instead of absolute URL.

Comment: @DVK, That totally makes sense, will check it now.

Comment: can you show the redirect page code